# Is primality essential in Varshamov's bound?

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory

Let $v_q(n,r)=\sum_{i=0}^r \binom{n}i (q-1)^i$ denote a number of points in a ball of radius $r$ in the Hamming metric on the cube $\Sigma^n$, where $|\Sigma|=q$. What is the maximal number of points in $\Sigma^n$ with mutual distances at least $d$ (later: $d$-distant point sets)? **Gilbert**'s bound says that we may find $M$ such points if $(M-1)\cdot v_q(n,d-1)< q^n$: add points one by one, while we have less than $M$ points, the $(d-1)$-balls centered at them do not cover $\Sigma^n$ and we may add another point. If $q$ is a power of prime, **Varshamov**'s bound improves the previous result by claiming that we may find $q^k$ $d$-distant points whenever $q^{k-1}v_q(n,d-1)<q^n$. For the proof, we identify $\Sigma$ with a finite field and consider the maximal subspace $X$ of $\Sigma^n$ into which all points are $d$-distant. If $\dim X\geqslant k$, we are done, else there exists a point $v$ not covered by $(d-1)$-balls centered at elements of $X$, and the span of $X$ and $v$ is larger $d$-distant subspace.

My question is: is Varshamov's bound true if we do not require that $q$ is a prime power (say, for $q=6$)? This often happens and always does astonish me when arithmetical properties like being prime powers are crucial for purely combinatorial or topological claims, and I wonder what is the situation in this particular case.

Comment: What is $\Sigma$? A cyclic group? Another abelian group?

Comment: @WillSawin Any set of cardinality $q$. We need no other structure for defining Hamming metric on $\Sigma^n$.

Comment: In my answer below I remark that perhaps a more natural question is whether Varshamov's bound holds for non-linear codes.

Comment: @Dima what do you mean? The claim "linear code exists" implies a claim "code exists".

Comment: @FedorPetrov Varshamov bound is a bound on the code size in terms of $d$, $n$ and $q$, which holds for linear codes. Does it hold for non-linear codes?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik It is _lower_ bound: it claims that somehow large code exists. Moreover, even a linear code of such size exists. Of course, not linear code also exists. Your question would be reasonable for upper bounds on the size of a code.

Comment: Gilbert bound is true if the code is not linear, but Varshamov bound is true for linear codes. also, binary cyclic codes are better than the Gilbert-
Varshamov bound for lengths up to 1023. For the case $q=6$, we must analyse $Z_6$ codes at the first step.

Comment: @FedorPetrov - oops, right. I was thinking about upper bounds too much...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The analogue of the Varshamov inequality need not hold for instance for $\lvert\Sigma\rvert=q=6$: For $n=4$ and $d=3$ it would give a code $C\subseteq\Sigma^4$ with $d(C)\ge3$ and $\lvert C\rvert=36$. But such a code gives a pair of orthogonal Latin squares of order $6$, which is known not to exist (by Tarry's negative answer to Euler's [thirty-six officers problem](http://Thirty-six%20officers%20problem)).

(The construction of the orthogonal pair $A,B$ is as follows: Since $d(C)\ge3$, the map $C\to\Sigma^2$, $(i,j,a,b)\mapsto(i,j)$ is bijective. For $(i,j,a,b)\in C$ let $A$ and $B$ have entry $a$ and $b$ in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column, respectively.)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

I hope I haven't misunderstood it but the discussion on p. 315 of Handbook of Coding Theory, Vol. 1, by Brouwer seems to imply that a finite field is necessary since it relies on adding a column to the parity check matrix that is not a linear combination of fewer than $d-1$ columns, so the argument is over a vector space. Having a module over a ring might be problematic in terms of applying this argument in general.

See also the short note "Lengthening and the Gilbert-Varshamov bound" by Edel and Bierbrauer [here](http://www.math.mtu.edu/~jbierbra/) where the techniques used include orthogonal arrays, but those array parameters come from guarantees on dual distances of codes, thus again rely on vector spaces. I don't know whether there are generic orthogonal array constructions that can be substituted in their place.

Comment: It is essential for this particular argument, but is it essential to the claim?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a terminological note than an answer.

Historically, Gilbert bound is often called Gilbert-Varshamov bound, adding to the confusion. (Wikipedia articles on it are quite messy too).
Gilbert bound does not need linearity of the *code* (i.e. the collection $C$ of points in $\Sigma^n$ with minimal pairwise Hamming distance $d$), whereas Varshamov's bound does.

IMHO it does not really matter whether $q$ is a prime power; what does matter is whether the minimal distance $d$ code in question  is linear or not (i.e. whether $C$ is an affine subspace of $\mathbb{F}_q$ or not). I won't be surprised if a nonlinear code beating Varshamov bound exists. Needless to say, all the codes for $q$ not a prime power are non-linear.

Also there is a closely related asymptotic Gilbert-Varshamov bound.
Codes beating the latter are known to exist since the classical work by [M.A. Tsfasman, S.G. Vlăduts,Th. Zink](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mana.19821090103/abstract) and [M.A. Tsfasman](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/bbfbd6c3200f8c0ff47fb1652e7a29a9/ppi1231.pdf), where
a "layman" exposition (in Russian) of the result it presented.
(A translation of the latter is in Problems of Information Transmission, 1982, 18:3, 163–166).

Due to this terminology clash, finding the relevant references is very hard indeed.